# Step siblings and relationships

Tags: philosophy, five-precepts, sutras, suttas

Lord Buddha once said

"The future humans will have unusual lusts and temptations"

So when i saw a this in a TV series i couldn't define the line,

If two step siblings form a romantic relationship is it against the five precepts?

So what if we say they are independent individuals,What then?

Answer (score 1):

As per the 20 unsuitable women listed, it could break the precept, depending on if one or both are in care of parents/relatives/guardian or if the king/government prohibits such relationships or if it's prohibited by tradition.

But one should keep in mind that taboo & obviously vulgar behaviors are not discussed under the 3rd precept. That doesn't mean that they don't fall under sexual misconduct.

Comment: So what if we say they are independent individuals,What then? @Sankha Kulanthille

Comment: Updated the answer

Comment: I agree with the update, But isn't everything we discover new as a social phenomenon considered  "Taboo" in the beginning? These people really exist and other than a legal bond making them siblings they actually have no connection  at all. We should consider more traditions before coming to a conclusion (Girls marrying their uncles - used to be very famous in india even in Lord Buddha's time). What actually should define "Taboo" is very hard to define.